# OpenZeppelin Contracts

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol

Why functionCall calls the other functionCall ?

I don't understand why they do nested callings instead of making one call to functionCall function ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see one of the functions has two, and the other has three input parameters. If you don't want to specify a special error message, you can directly call the function which has two parameters. It just gives you some flexibility.